# Grab 2 values from table where it contains certain data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I need the query string to be able to find 2 values that are inserted by the user by their name.

One of each value should be in `Ingredient1` and in `Ingredient2` (not both). How would you be able to do this in the sql query?

This is what I've tried so far

```cs
public static List<IngredientModel> LoadSearchRecipes(string ingredientCategory, string ingredientCategory1)
{
    // select ingredient category to show results
    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM dbo.Recipe WHERE Ingredient1 IN('" + ingredientCategory.ToString() + "," + ingredientCategory.ToString() + "') AND WHERE Ingredient1 IN('" + ingredientCategory.ToString() + "," + ingredientCategory.ToString() + "');"; 

     return SqlDataAccess.LoadData<IngredientModel>(sql);
}
```

Comment: Yikes, this looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running MySQL? Schema `dbo` suggest SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

> One of each value should be in Ingredient1 and in Ingredient2 (not both)

In MySQL, you could evaluate both conditions as integers, and ensure the sum is just `1`:

```
where (ingredient1 = ?) + (ingredient2 = ?) = 1
```

Actually I suspect that you are not using MySQL. Here is a standard approach for other databases:

```
where 
    (case when ingredient1 = ? then 1 else 0 end) 
    + (case when ingredient2 = ? then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

The question marks should be replaced with the value of your parameter (the syntax for bind parameter may vary across databases).